# Writing DWORD to memory overwrites only 1 byte instead of 4

Tags: c++, overwrite, dword

I have

```
typedef unsigned int DWORD;

void write_str(string str, char** buf) {
    DWORD len = str.size();
    **buf = len;
    *buf += sizeof(len);
    memcpy(*buf, str.c_str(), len);
    *buf += len;
}
```

This code, and only 1 byte is overwriten in `**buf = len;` if i have i.e. 7 in len while 4 should be, since sizeof(DWORD) = 4

Comment: Only 1 byte is assigned to `**buf` because that's all it can hold.

Comment: Oh, I'm so blind :(, thanks. Post it as answer, I'll close question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `buf` is a `char **`, `**buf` is a `char`. It can hold only a single byte. Therefore, only a single byte is written to it.

Answer (score 1):

Fix:

```
DWORD *tmpptr(*buf);
*tmpptr = len;
```

C++ is automatically casting len to a char, since that is what `*buf` is.

Answer (score 0):

You have the parameter

```
char** buf
```

Meaning that `**buf` is a char, which is very likely a single byte.

Answer (score 0):

1 byte is overwritten since the destination type is char (the type of `**buf` is char). This is correct. But the expression `*buf += sizeof(len)` has no meaning in my opinion.